# SFMC - Use image in SFTP in an email

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ssjs, images, sftp

An external platform generates QR images and leaves them in SFMC's SFTP. I want to use these images to insert them into an email. I know that if the image is in a Content Builder folder I can use the Ampscript "ContentImagebyKey" function. But I would like to know if there is a similar function to get the image from a SFTP folder or maybe combining Automation Studio and a Script Activity to move the image from the SFTP folder to a Content Builder folder.

Another approach is to have the external platform send the QR image via an "asset" API call, but this is my last option because that means more development time for an external team.

Thanks for your comments and help.

Comment: Honestly, the easiest solution is the option using the API. There is no native way via SSJS or AMPscript to interact with the SFTP - meaning you would either have to use an external service to grab from SFTP and then push into system, likely need to do so via API or to have your current service creating the images push to SFMC via API. Only other option is to host these on a 3rd party system with public URLs that you can then use to reference in the Email and not host them on SFMC.

Comment: I don’t think what you’re asking is possible, although you might try the [AttachFile()](https://ampscript.guide/attachfile/) function - but then it will attach, not embed the QR code. Another option would be to generate the QR codes on the fly as described here: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2022/03/22/generating-barcodes-and-qr-codes-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud/